# Mixture Density Networks with shared centroids

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to define a particular variant of mixture density networks where, for each sample in a batch, the neural network predicts a distribution of centroids (each of which is a Gaussian with a full covariance matrix).  The caveat is that I'd like to learn the location and covariance matrix of each centroid (ie, it should be a *parameter* of the neural network) and then predict a distribution over each centroid.

I've seen lots of examples (ie, http://edwardlib.org/tutorials/mixture-density-network) where the neural network is outputting means, sigmas and alphas for each sample.  I want to learn means and sigmas, and then just output alphas.

I'm trying to do this with the following code:

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype='float32', shape=(None, output_ndim), name='inputs')
alphas = tf.placeholder(name='alphas', dtype='float32', shape=(None, num_mixtures))

mu = tf.Variable(name='mu', dtype='float32',
                 initial_value=true_means, trainable=True)

sigma_chol = tf.Variable(name='sigma_chol', dtype='float32',
                         initial_value=true_sigmas, trainable=True)

components=[
    tfd.MultivariateNormalTriL(loc=mu[i],
                               scale_tril=sigma_chol[i],
                               validate_args=True,
                               name='Mixture_Component_{}'.format(i)) for i in range(num_mixtures)
]


bimix_gauss = tfd.Mixture(cat=tfd.Categorical(alphas),
                          components=components, validate_args=True)
```

But this throws an error because the mixture parameter (`alphas`) is of higher rank than the means and sigmas:

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in merge_with(self, other)
    666       try:
--> 667         self.assert_same_rank(other)
    668         new_dims = []

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in assert_same_rank(self, other)
    711         raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s must have the same rank" % (self,
--> 712                                                                        other))
    713 

ValueError: Shapes (?,) and () must have the same rank

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-a0aab2614708> in <module>()
     17 
     18 bimix_gauss = tfd.Mixture(cat=tfd.Categorical(alphas),
---> 19                           components=components, validate_args=True)
     20 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distributions/python/ops/mixture.py in __init__(self, cat, components, validate_args, allow_nan_stats, use_static_graph, name)
    139     for d in components:
    140       static_event_shape = static_event_shape.merge_with(d.event_shape)
--> 141       static_batch_shape = static_batch_shape.merge_with(d.batch_shape)
    142     if static_event_shape.ndims is None:
    143       raise ValueError(

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in merge_with(self, other)
    671         return TensorShape(new_dims)
    672       except ValueError:
--> 673         raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are not compatible" % (self, other))
    674 
    675   def concatenate(self, other):

ValueError: Shapes (?,) and () are not compatible
```

I could fix this by manually writing the likelihood (it's messy, but not that messy) - but I'm sure there's a better way of doing this using tensorflow.distributions.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these inputs are tensors, so you can always apply operations before. Here, you probably want to `tile` the means and sigmas to the entire batch.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tfd = tf.contrib.distributions

num_mixtures = 7
output_ndim = 5

inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype='float32', shape=(None, output_ndim), name='inputs')
alphas = tf.placeholder(name='alphas', dtype='float32', shape=(None, num_mixtures))

mu = tf.Variable(name='mu', dtype='float32',
                 initial_value=tf.zeros((output_ndim, num_mixtures)), trainable=True)

sigma_chol = tf.Variable(name='sigma_chol', dtype='float32',
                         initial_value=tf.zeros((output_ndim, output_ndim, num_mixtures)), trainable=True)


# tile distribution parameters to the entire batch
batch_size = tf.shape(inputs)[0]
mu = tf.tile(mu[None], (batch_size, 1, 1))
sigma_chol = tf.tile(sigma_chol[None], (batch_size, 1, 1, 1))

components=[
    tfd.MultivariateNormalTriL(loc=mu[...,i],
                               scale_tril=sigma_chol[...,i],
                               validate_args=True,
                               name='Mixture_Component_{}'.format(i)) for i in range(num_mixtures)
]

bimix_gauss = tfd.Mixture(cat=tfd.Categorical(alphas),
                          components=components, validate_args=True)
```